# Check if all imports are possible without running a script

Tags: python

## Problem description

I have a huge project where there are a lots of python files. Unfortunately this project is not properly covered by the tests and we are facing problems with... imports :)

My goal is to **execute a 'dry run' of all python scripts(without executing them)** just to make sure that **all modules are properly imported(especially these local modules)** and list all invalid scripts where all imports are impossible.

## Example

Let me give you 1st example(script1.py):

```
from NON_EXISTING_local_module import non_existing_class
import time


def test_something():
    time.sleep(10)


test_something()
```

Import of NON_EXISTING_local_module is impossible like it's done normally in Python by ImportError exception(script1.py marked as invalid)

2nd example(script2.py):

```
from EXSISTING_local_module import existing_class
import time


def test_something():
    time.sleep(10)


test_something()
```

And here I would like to see that everything is fine(no problems with imports) **and that the method test_something() is not executed at all(no need to wait 10s)**(script2.py marked as valid)

## My research

I know that there is an option to execute and get result of it:

```
python -c 'import module'
```

but it does not work with local modules

What is more RobotFramework has such option as --dryrun as it's described here:
http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#dry-run
I'm looking for exactly the same solution but for pure python scripts.

Thanks a lot in advance for any hints!

Comment: Take a look into https://www.pylint.org/

Comment: @YaroslavSurzhikov: this looks nice! Thanks

Comment: Just for the record: your scripts should use the `if __name__ == "__main__"` test to prevent execution on import, cf https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do